# Find the general solution of this pde?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a final in my PDE Class and needs some help with a review problem.

Find the general solution of the equation for $v=v(x,y)$: $$x\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=2xy(x^2-y^2)$$

Sorry its probably a straight forward problem.

Comment: Not sure this is the intended way, but since the right hand side is just a simple polynomial it looks like we can get ridd of this if we take an ansatz (of the same form as the rhs) $v(x,y) = u(x,y) + ax^3y + bxy^3$. Substituting this into the PDE leads to $xu_x + yu_y = x^3y[2-4a] + y^3x[-4b-2] = 0$ so if we take $a=1/2$ and $b=-1/2$ we are left with the PDE $xu_x + yu_y = 0$ which can be solved using for example using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

Comment: ...btw you don't need the simplifying trick to solve the PDE: you can just apply the method of characteristics directly on your equation.